# Oracle SQL Join two tables/views avoid cross product

Tags: sql, oracle, microsoft-query

I have two tables/views that I am trying to join properly. They are `V_ARINVOICE_ALL` and `V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS`. The third table `V_ARINVOICE_ALL` in the following image is just for extra explanation.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USv2p.png)

I'm currently getting the wrong amount of rows being returned because of, I think, kind of a cross join. I am trying to join `Credit` from `V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS`.

I use the following SQL query to join `V_ARINVOICE_ALL` and `V_ARINVOICE_ALL` and I get the all the right results except for the `Credit which isn't selected:

```
SELECT 
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE,
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_COMPANY,
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO,
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_NO


FROM   
IQMS.V_ARINVOICE_ALL V_ARINVOICE_ALL 


INNER JOIN
IQMS.V_GLACCT V_GLACCT
ON
  V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLACCT_ID_SALES = V_GLACCT.ID AND V_GLACCT.ACCT = '3648-00-0'



WHERE 
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO = 'OX01' 
AND 
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE >= TO_DATE('05/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND
V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE <= TO_DATE('15/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

ORDER BY 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE
```

> Result (41 Rows)

```
  |INVOICE_DATE|...| INVOICE|
  +------------+---+--------+
  |  05/04/2016|...|  494658|
  |  20/05/2016|...|  495274|
  |  20/05/2016|...|  495275|
```

But when I try and join `V_ARINVOICE_ALL` and `V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS` with the following query:

```
SELECT 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_COMPANY,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_NO,
 V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.CREDIT AS "INCOME"


FROM   
 IQMS.V_ARINVOICE_ALL V_ARINVOICE_ALL 


INNER JOIN
 IQMS.V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS
ON
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLBATCHID_ID = V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.ID
 AND V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLPERIODS_ID_AR = V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.GLPERIODS_ID
 AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.DESCRIP LIKE '%OX01%ITEMS%' AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.ACCT = '3648-00-0'



WHERE 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO = 'OX01' 
AND 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE >= TO_DATE('05/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE <= TO_DATE('15/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

ORDER BY 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE
```

> I get something like: (165 Rows)

```
  |INVOICE_DATE|...| INVOICE|  INCOME|
  +------------+---+--------+--------+
  |  ...       |...|  ...   |   ...  |
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     450|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     450|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     450|
  |  ...       |...|  ...   |   ...  |
```

> Desired result (41 Rows)

```
  |INVOICE_DATE|...| INVOICE|  INCOME|
  +------------+---+--------+--------+
  |  ...       |...|  ...   |   ...  |
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     450|
  |  ...       |...|  ...   |   ...  |
```

I'm a bit more familiar with joins than I was before. But I'm not certain I'm doing them right. I've tried right join, right outer join, left join, left outer join, etc. What am I doing wrong here?

---

EDIT2: First edit was bad made no sense. I don't know if this helps but there is only two rows that would be

```
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
  |  23/06/2016|...|  495667|     225|
```

in the table which match the `WHERE` clause on the Join : `V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLPERIODS_ID_AR = V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.GLPERIODS_ID AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.DESCRIP LIKE '%OX01%ITEMS%' AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.ACCT = '3648-00-0`

But would still get it more than twice. So I imagine it has something to do with the relationship being 1 to Many. Which I'm not sure how to deal with.

If that's any help.

---

If you need more info feel free to ask.

Comment: why tag this with excel, I see no excel at all here.

Comment: Sorry. This is being done in excels power query. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a one to many relationship. There are more values in the COGS table than you require (likely another column filled with other data).

Try `SELECT DISTINCT` to limit to unique values on selected columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- DISTINCT goes here
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_COMPANY,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO,
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_NO,
 V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.CREDIT AS "INCOME"


FROM   
 IQMS.V_ARINVOICE_ALL V_ARINVOICE_ALL 


INNER JOIN
 IQMS.V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS
ON
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLBATCHID_ID = V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.ID
 AND V_ARINVOICE_ALL.GLPERIODS_ID_AR = V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.GLPERIODS_ID
 AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.DESCRIP LIKE '%OX01%ITEMS%' AND V_GLBATCH_AR_COGS.ACCT = '3648-00-0'



WHERE 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO = 'OX01' 
AND 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE >= TO_DATE('05/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE <= TO_DATE('15/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

ORDER BY 
 V_ARINVOICE_ALL.INVOICE_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only problem is that there would be some rows where there would have to be two or three duplicates of rows unfortunately :(